# Make my own UIControlEvent, and trigger it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications

I have a custom class of a UIView I've made inside my viewcontroller. I want to make this class re-usable and so don't want to build it to work just with this 1 viewcontroller. Because of this, I *think* the best way of telling my viewcontroller that the user has interacted with the class is to somehow make my own UIControlEvent. Maybe something like:

```
[customClass addTarget:self action:@selector(whatIWantToHappen) forControlEvents:UIControlEventWhatever];
```

I don't know much about doing this though, any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this by subclassing `UIControl`, which inherits from UIView, but provides some additional methods for handling targets and actions. Have a look at the [constants](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW65), perhaps one of the predefined control events already fits your bill. Otherwise, you could define your own events in the range provided by `UIControlEventApplicationReserved`, you should however *never* prefix your own things with `UI...`, that 'namespace' is reserved for UIKit.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by omz, you may get a compiler warning when doing this:

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(selector:) forControlEvents:CustomControlEvent];
```

The compiler doesn't like the custom value being used for the last parameter, which is of type `UIControlEvents`, so it throws a warning.

I did this:

```
enum CustomControlEvent : UIControlEvents
{
    CustomControlEventWHATEVER  =   UIControlEventApplicationReserved
};
typedef enum CustomControlEvent CustomControlEvent;
```

Behold! No more warnings.

I found this notation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7424737/543814) StackOverflow answer.

N.B. For `UIControlEvents`, I am strongly avoiding the use of any unavailable values, so I only use the **`UIControlEventApplicationReserved`** value.

Additionally, the typedef relinquishes the need to type 'enum' every time and is customary.

Comment: Timo, this may be a bit late, but UIControlEventApplicationReserved is not a value, it's a bit mask (it's even commented as “range available for application use”). It's defined as 0x0F000000, so you should use 0x01000000, 0x02000000, 0x04000000 and 0x08000000 as your custom events.

Comment: This line `enum CustomControlEvent : UIControlEvents` gives me an error saying uicontrolevents is an invalid underlying type

Comment: @rounak It has been a long time since I wrote this... This solution may have broken along the way!