# Objective-C algorithm to find largest common subsets of arrays?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, algorithm

I'm currently in need of an efficient solution to finding the **largest common** subsets of multiple arrays.

For example:
Let's say a user, Chris, wants to find other users with common interests (from most common to least common); we'd have to compare his array of interests with other users' arrays and find the largest common subset to the smallest common subset.

> Chris {bowling, gaming, skating, running}

And other users in database.

> Brad {bowling, jumping, walking, sitting}
>   John {bowling, gaming, skating, eating}
>   Sarah {bowling, gaming, drawing, coding}

So Chris has the most common interests, respectively, with John, then Sarah, then Brad.

How would I, in Objective-C, be able to do this? Any pointers would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421516/enum-defining-forms-in-objective-c this probably can help you on comparison

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for an algorithm to find the cardinality of a set intersection.

Depending on your set representation, you could choose different ways of doing it. The most performant representation for this would be using bits in an integer, but if the number of possible interests exceeds 64 this may not be easy to implement.

A straightforward way of implementing it would be with `NSMutableSet`, like this:

```
// Prepare the individual lists
NSArray *chris = @[@"bowling", @"gaming", @"skating", @"running"];
NSArray *brad =  @[@"bowling", @"jumping", @"walking", @"sitting"];
// Obtain the intersection
NSMutableSet *common = [NSMutableSet setWitArray:chris];
[common intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:brad]];
NSLog(@"Common interest count: %i", common.count);
```

Comment: One question: If I were to store the users' interests in a string value instead of an array, would finding a common substring be easier/more efficient than dealing with arrays?

Comment: @JacobBrubaker No, it would be different, because you'd be looking for the longest common subsequence - a reasonably complex algorithm ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)). How many different possibilities are there for an interest string?

Comment: Infinite possibilities; the users create their own interests, so there's not really a set interest option to choose from. Do you think limiting the users to only choosing from a set of interests would be more efficient in terms of set intersection?

Comment: @JacobBrubaker Yes, limiting the choices would let you speed up the search. If you could limit the list to choosing from, say, 64 standard items, then obtaining an intersection of two sets would be as easy as `AND`ing two bit sets together. However, the effect is not going to be significant until user count gets into thousands or even millions.

Comment: Hey man, one question: can you please explain why "if the number of possible interests exceeds 64 this may not be easy to implement"? Sorry for the late question. I get how it could slow the search down, but how can it hinder the said implementation?

Comment: @JacobBrubaker An implementation with a single 64-bit `long long` is simpler than an implementation with an array of bytes. With arrays, what used to be a single operation on `long long` becomes a loop; what used to be a single loop on `long long`s becomes two nested loops, and so on.