# Define my own UIControlEvent

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipod, uicontrol, uicontrolevents

I need to define my own `UIControlEvent` to do something like

```
[activeField sendActionsForControlEvents:MYEvent];
```

how to override `UIControlEvents`?

Comment: This is just how to listen to a control event. I just needs to fire my own event as already defined events are not matched to my requirement.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6141455/751026

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make my own UIControlEvent, and trigger it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141455/make-my-own-uicontrolevent-and-trigger-it)